# Get ODATA Element Names and Data Types in C# or Iterate EdmCollectionType

Tags: c#, odata, metadata

Here I'm getting the entity name but I can't get the element names and their data types though I see them in the debugger as shown in image below.

The debugger image shows the path to the element data types starting with "entity.Type.ElementType" but Intellisense shows "ElementType" is not an option though I see it in the debugger image.

[image: Code gets entity name but how to get element name and data type]

[image: Debugger path to element name and data type]

I see the path to the datatype is variable entity->Type-> elementtype-> definition-> declaredproperties-> type-> definition-> name but intellisense won't help get to that level.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w9aV.png)

Comment: Type is a EdmCollectionType which is not IEnumerable so I can't iterate it. How do I the lower levels of an EdmCollectionType?

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually worked:

```
 var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(baseUrl + "$metadata");
            var settings = new ODataMessageReaderSettings() { MessageQuotas = new ODataMessageQuotas() { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 35000000 } };
            var metadataMessage = new ClientHttpResponseMessage((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse());

            using (var messageReader = new ODataMessageReader(metadataMessage, settings))
            {
                IEdmModel edmModel = messageReader.ReadMetadataDocument();

                foreach (var entity in edmModel.EntityContainer.EntitySets())
                {
                    string entityName = entity.Name; // entity name

                    IEdmCollectionType edmCollectionType = (IEdmCollectionType)entity.Type;
                    IEdmType edmType = edmCollectionType.ElementType.Definition;
                    IEdmStructuredType edmStructuredType = edmType as IEdmStructuredType;

                    foreach (IEdmProperty property in edmStructuredType.DeclaredProperties)
                    {
                        string propertyName = property.Name;

                        IEdmType edmType2 = property.Type.Definition;
                        var primitive = edmType2 as IEdmPrimitiveType;
                        string elementName = primitive.Name;


                    }
                }

            }
```